# Need urlrewrite for proxypass enabled server

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, proxypass

I have a application deployed in tomcat(app1), front end by appache web server. So if i hit onlinetamilportal.com then it will point to onlinetamilportal.com:8080/app1. Which is working fine.

What i want is url rewrite, www.onlinetamilportal.com/showPost.jsp?serial=deivamagal should rewrite www.onlinetamilportal.com/serial/deivamagal. how to acheive this? Tried lot of rewrite rule for the past 4-5 days. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.onlinetamilportal.com
      ProxyPass /        ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/app1/ smax=0 ttl=60 retry=5
      ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/app1
</VirtualHost>
```